# Erdas gmdx to gmd?

Tags: erdas-imagine

I have some spatial models in gmdx format which I couldn't open in erdas 9.2.

Is there any way to open gmdx files into erdas 9.2?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately gmdx could not be opened with previous versions of erdas.

In fact gmdx is an xml file format that you can open it in a text support sotware like notepad.

Note operators and data values.this way is useful in case of gmdx could not be opened even in  recent versions due to bad data value or expression.

However you can use this way to understand model architecture by inspection of xml tags.